# Adding Clicked Row + Next Row at the End of the HTML Table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the clicked row + next row to the end of an HTML table. For some reason when I use the `originalRow.next()` code it adds the row as the top row of the HTML table. I want it to be added to the bottom of the table and not the top.

```
 var rowId = $("#menuToolsetTemplate").attr("rowId");
    var originalRow = $("#" + rowId);
  var rowToBeAdded = $("#" + rowId).clone();


    // when adding module level
    if ($(rowToBeAdded).attr("class") == "PARENTROWCONTENTS") {

    $("#tblTemplate_Body").append(rowToBeAdded);
    $("#tblTemplate_Body").append($(originalRow).next()); 

}
```

The `originalRow` is the row on which the user clicked. I make a clone of that row and add to the bottom of the table. I also need to add the `oringinalRow.next` to the bottom of the table.

Comment: Perhaps if you $originalRow.appendTo($("#tblTemplate_Body")) it would work. Also can I suggest you try adding a dollar sign to your variable names that represent jquery objects? That way you can easily remember that you do not need to wrap it in a jquery selector when you use it again later. ;)

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle so we can see the behavior exhibiting itself?

Comment: @Adam I want to add a clone of the clicked row and the next row and then add to the bottom of the table.

Comment: I got it working after performing a clone! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [tr:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) and [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) functions.. Check my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9hNQU/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" border="1px" >
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#mytable tr').on ('click', function () {

    var $this_cloned = $(this).clone();
    var $nextRow = $(this).next(); //Not sure if you wanted to clone the next row or move

    $('#mytable tr:last').after($this_cloned);
    $('#mytable tr:last').after($nextRow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to clone the original row and also the next row and then add to the table using the append method.